# Are created and modified the two fields every database table should have?

Tags: database, rdbms

I recently realized that I add some form of row creation timestamp and possibly a "updated on" field to most of my tables. Suddenly I started thinking that perhaps every table in the database should have a `created` and `modified` field that are set in the model behind the scenes.

Does this sound correct? Are there any types of high-load tables (like sessions) or massive sized tables that this wouldn't be a good idea for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't put those fields (which I generally call audit fields) on **every** database table.  If it's a low-traffic, high-value table (like `Users`, for instance), it goes on, no question. I'd also add `creator` and `modifier`. If it's a table that gets hit a **lot** (an operation history table, say), then maybe the benefit isn't worth the cost of increased insert time and storage space.

It's a call you'll need to make separately for each table.

Answer (score 3):

Obviously, there isn't a single rule.

Most of my tables have date-related things, DateCreated, DateModified, and occasionally a Revision to track changes and so on. Do whatever makes sense. Clearly, you can invent cases where it's appropriate and cases where it is not. If you're asking whether you should add them "by default" to most tables, I'd say "probably".